# Regarding QScreen::grabWindow() crashes

Tags: qt

I use QScreen::GrabWindow(nullptr), sometimes it would crash. it's stack is like this:

```
RaiseException() : [KERNELBASE] (File: N/A @Line N/A)
CxxThrowException() : [VCRUNTIME140] (File: N/A @Line N/A)
QGridLayoutEngine::rowCount() : [Qt5Gui] (File: N/A @Line N/A)
QGridLayoutEngine::rowCount() : [Qt5Gui] (File: N/A @Line N/A)
QMovie::updated() : [Qt5Gui] (File: N/A @Line N/A)
qt_pixmapFromWinHBITMAP() : [Qt5Gui] (File: N/A @Line N/A)
N/A() : [qwindows] (File: N/A @Line N/A)
QScreen::grabWindow() : [Qt5Gui] (File: N/A @Line N/A)
```

how about this api's stability? or I should use gdi directly?

Comment: Why are you passing `nullptr` as a window id?

Comment: I need to capture the desktop